# Redirect to a different route from within a ngRoute $routeProvider resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I have a situation in which based on a certain condition, if a user access a certain route ('/checkinsuccess') before that controller and view loads a function gets run that checks if a certain flag is true using routeProviders resolve property. If this flag is true it redirects to a new route. Unfortunately it seems like the initial view and controller that I'm trying to redirect away from ('/checkinsuccess') are loading before the function being called in the resolve property finishes. This is causing issue since that initial view runs an auto logout function. Is there a way to run the check before the initial route loads, I thought that's what resolve did? Here's a piece of my code.

```
.when('/checkinsuccess', {
        controller: 'thankuctrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/MobileCheckin/checkin-success.html',
        resolve: {
            checkForWorkflowUpdates: function($location){
                checkForWorkflowUpdates($location)   
            }                                                   
        }

 // check if workflow update has been made and load that route if true.
 function checkForWorkflowUpdates($location){
     var selectedForms = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedForms'));
        if (selectedForms) {
            if(selectedForms.workersComp){
                $location.path('/workerscomp');
            } else if (selectedForms.motorVehical) {
                $location.path('/autoaccident');
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: I use the resolve to fetch and build models that I inject into my controller. Any reason why you can't add that `checkForWorkflowUpdates` logic to whereever `/checkinsuccess` is invoked?

Comment: I tried that, but then it flashes the initial view for a split second before redirecting. Also there are several different dynamic points of entry to this route, so I can't really add it to every controller that may load it.

Comment: Not returning anything from the function ... try returning a promise and resolve or reject accordingly. Controller won't load if it is rejected

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Know of any good examples for this? @charlietfl